# How do I upload an image in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, file-upload

How do I upload an image in Magento ?

Magento ver. `1.9.3.4`

I tried to upload a picture but the system does not accept it.

Comment: is there any specific format? or please upload the screenshot.

Comment: Specify the issue into details, where you are try to upload image and what magento error you are facing?